# How to build libobs as dependency of obs-studio-node module?

Tags: cmake, cpack, obs-studio

I am trying [obs-studio-node](https://github.com/stream-labs/obs-studio-node).
This module require `libobs` as dependency. While building this module it download a pre-built version of `libobs` if none is specified. We can specify out custom `libobs` as mentioned in `README.md`

I followed these steps to build `libobs`. These steps are listed in [`README.md`](https://github.com/stream-labs/obs-studio-node)

1. `git clone https://github.com/stream-labs/obs-studio`
2. `cd obs-studio`
3. `git submodule update --init --recursive`
4. `mkdir build`
5. `cd build`
6. `cmake .. -DENABLE_UI=false -DDepsPath="C:\Users\alokm\Downloads\dependencies2019\win64" -DENABLE_SCRIPTING=false -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64`
7. `cmake --build .`
8. `cpack -G ZIP`

Last step (`cpack -G ZIP`) is failing with errors

```
PS C:\Users\alokm\tmp\streamlabs\obs-studio\build> cpack -G ZIP
CPack: Create package using ZIP
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Install project: obs-studio []
CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/w32-pthreads/cmake_install.cmake:51 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/w32-pthreads/Release/w32-pthreads.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/glad/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/glad/Release/obsglad.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/deps/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-d3d11/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-d3d11/Release/libobs-d3d11.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-winrt/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-winrt/Release/libobs-winrt.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-opengl/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs-opengl/Release/libobs-opengl.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs/cmake_install.cmake:51 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/libobs/Release/obs.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:57 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/coreaudio-encoder/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/coreaudio-encoder/Release/coreaudio-encoder.dll":
  File exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-wasapi/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-wasapi/Release/win-wasapi.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-dshow/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-dshow/Release/win-dshow.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/Release/win-capture.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/graphics-hook/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/graphics-hook/Release/graphics-hook64.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/cmake_install.cmake:59 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/get-graphics-offsets/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/get-graphics-offsets/Release/get-graphics-offsets64.exe":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/cmake_install.cmake:64 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/inject-helper/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/inject-helper/Release/inject-helper64.exe":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-capture/cmake_install.cmake:69 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/decklink/win/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/decklink/win/Release/win-decklink.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:57 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-mf/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/win-mf/Release/win-mf.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-qsv11/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-qsv11/Release/obs-qsv11.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:67 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/enc-amf/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/enc-amf/Release/enc-amf.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:77 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/enc-amf/amf-test/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/enc-amf/amf-test/Release/enc-amf-test64.exe":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/enc-amf/cmake_install.cmake:59 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:77 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-openvr/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-openvr/Release/win-openvr.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:87 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/motion-effect/src/motion-transition/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/motion-effect/src/motion-transition/Release/motion-transition.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/motion-effect/cmake_install.cmake:38 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:92 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-vst/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-vst/Release/obs-vst.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:97 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/image-source/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/image-source/Release/image-source.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:102 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-x264/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-x264/Release/obs-x264.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:107 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/Release/obs-ffmpeg.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:117 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-mux/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/ffmpeg-mux/Release/obs-ffmpeg-mux.exe":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/cmake_install.cmake:59 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:117 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-outputs/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-outputs/Release/obs-outputs.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:122 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-filters/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-filters/Release/obs-filters.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:127 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-transitions/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-transitions/Release/obs-transitions.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:132 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-text/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-text/Release/obs-text.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:137 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/rtmp-services/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/rtmp-services/Release/rtmp-services.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:142 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/text-freetype2/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/text-freetype2/Release/text-freetype2.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:147 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ndi/cmake_install.cmake:37 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/obs-ndi/Release/obs-ndi.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:152 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/slobs-virtual-cam/windows/obs-virtual-cam/src/virtual-output/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
":
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/slobs-virtual-cam/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/slobs-virtual-cam/windows/obs-virtual-cam/src/virtual-source/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/slobs-virtual-cam/windows/obs-virtual-cam/src/virtual-source/Release/obs-virtualsource.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/slobs-virtual-cam/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/plugins/cmake_install.cmake:157 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:62 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/UI/obs-frontend-api/cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/UI/obs-frontend-api/Release/obs-frontend-api.dll":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/UI/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  C:/Users/alokm/tmp/streamlabs/obs-studio/build/cmake_install.cmake:67 (include)


CPack Error: Error when generating package: OBS Studio (64bit)
```

I guess [obs-studio](https://github.com/stream-labs/obs-studio) does not support `cpack` so its failing.
How can I build my custom `libobs` for `obs-studio-node` mobule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what exact configuration you have built. The output of CPack tries to install the `Release` configuration. However, you didn't mention any when did project configuration (and it may project-dependent to set some defaults).

Try add explicitly what you want:

```
$ cmake .. -DENABLE_UI=false -DDepsPath="C:\Users\alokm\Downloads\dependencies2019\win64" -DENABLE_SCRIPTING=false -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
$ cmake --build . --config Release
```

Comment: please help me similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575911/not-able-to-build-32-bit-obs-studio-node-with-custom-libobs